# Cinnamon - Windows do not minimize completely after update of LInux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I recently upgraded my Linux Mint (sequentially) from 20.1 to 21 using `mintupdate` / `mintupgrade`. Now I am experiencing strange behaviour: If I minimize a window clicking the button on the top right, it stays open. I can still move the window around and resize it, but I cannot interact with any of the content of the window anymore. To "use" the window again, I have to maximize it again from the panel icon, even though it was not completely minimized before.

I do not know how to fix this behaviour. My cinnamon version is 5.4.9.
I tried using `sudo apt install --reinstall --fix-broken cinnamon-*`, but the comman ddoes not finish because `cinnamon-control-center-goa` requires an outdated version of `cinnamon-control-center` that can't be installed, apparently.

Do you have any ideas on what I could try? If more system information is needed, I can gladly provide it. If all else fails I'll just try a clean install. I wanted to try kde for a while anyways

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix coming to the [windowManger.js](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/commit/7dac334cf1ce4507718b00ef9c9ba0f26d8eb965) file.   I manually changed the file on my system and so far the issue is resolved.